# Tips on linking SW and HW simulation.

Tags: verilog, simulation

I am total layman about this topic and I would appreciate experienced users to give me some useful tips and hints. I develop some code for arm cortex m0 which I want to simulate in `qemu` (it is not a problem cause it is well described). My processor is going to work with external flash, which verilog model I am in the possession of. The issue is that I got no idea what would be the best way to simulate my HW and SW simultaneously. I would appreciate some advice where to start, what programs you would recommend and if it is hard to get into these topics? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simulating a processor with a verilog model of a memory is far to slow unless you only need to simulate a few thousend cycles. I think you'll need a high level model of the memory.

Comment: Do you think converting it from verilog to C or C++ and then simulating as user space application would be appropriate ?

Answer (score 2):

A good source for this kind of information is DVCon.org papers. I wrote a paper on [Easy Steps Towards Virtual Prototyping using the SystemVerilog DPI](https://verificationacademy.com/news/featured-technical-papers-dvcon-2013) that should give you a basic introduction a where to start.